# Traducir un SweetAlert2 sin refrescar la página (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

Tengo este código Javascript dónde puedo cambiar traducir mi página sin necesidad de recargar:

```js
var strings = {
    espanol: {
        lang: "Idioma",
        texto1: "Hola!"
    },
    english: {
        lang: "Language",
        texto1: "Hi!"
    }
}

$( ".espanol" ).on( "click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("lang", "espanol");
    localizeStrings('espanol');
});
$( ".english" ).on( "click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("lang", "english");
    localizeStrings('english');
});

var Lang = localStorage.getItem("lang") || "english";
localizeStrings(Lang);
function localizeStrings(strLang) {
    $(strings[strLang]).each(function(key, lang){
        $.each(lang, function(id, string) {
            $("#"+id).html(string);
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="lang">Idioma</button>
<h1 id="texto1">Hola!</h1>
```

Y dentro de otro archivo Javascript **tengo un código que al terminar un proceso, saltaba un `alert` que reemplacé por un SweetAlert2:**

```
Swal.fire({
  text: "Algo está mal!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttonsStyling: false,
  confirmButtonText: "Entiendo",
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: "btn btn-warning"
  }
})
```

Quiero saber si hay forma de traducir el SweetAlert sin refrescar simplemente asignando de alguna manera un ID y de ahí poder tomarlo con mi código ya mencionado?

Quiero traducir del sweetalert: `text: "Algo está mal!",` y el texto del botón: `confirmButtonText: "Entiendo",`

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega las cadenas necesarias en el objeto:

```
let strings = {
    espanol: {
        lang: "Idioma",
        texto1: "Hola!",
        alertTxt: 'Algo está mal',
        alertBtn: 'Entendido'
    },
    english: {
        lang: "Language",
        texto1: "Hi!",
        alertTxt: 'Something is wrong',
        alertBtn: 'Got it'
    }
};
```

Crea una función para obtener la cadena a traducir:

```
function translate(str) {
    if(!strings.hasOwnProperty(Lang) || !strings[Lang].hasOwnProperty(str)) {
        // El idioma o la cadena a traducir (propiedad) no existe
        return str;
    }
    // Devolver traducción
    return strings[Lang][str];
}
```

Después usas la función para traducir las cadenas al crear la alerta, así no tienes que modificar elementos HTML que, por cierto, solo existen cuando se muestra la alerta:

```
Swal.fire({
  text: translate('alertTxt'),
  icon: "warning",
  buttonsStyling: false,
  confirmButtonText: translate('alertBtn'),
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: "btn btn-warning"
  }
});
```

Comment: Hola, seguí los pasos tal cual me los pusiste, incluso puse todo junto pero me sale "alerTxt is not defined" [Como se ve aquí](https://i.imgur.com/qrpdTVM.png) :(

Comment: Ya probé y rectifiqué que todo esté bien escrito y no encuentro el error :(

Comment: @NotoriusSha, cierto, se me escapó ese pequeño detalle, los parámetros deben ir entre comillas: `translate('alertTxt')`  ya corregí la respuesta.